# override admin product information page

Tags: overrides, products-management

I was created admin module for manage supplier information, next I want to add supplier list drop down to product details ( catalog > manage product > Inventory >) How to do it ?

Comment: Read this maybe it helps: http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2012/11/product-attribute-with-custom-options.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1:
Copy

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Inventory.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Inventory.php
```

Create a function here which give list of all  supplier list and

Step2:goto app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/tab/inventory.phtml create drop down using step1 define function

**Edit:**
add this code:

```
 <?php
$this->getSupplierList()
 ?>
 <select id="supplierlist" name="supplierlist" class="select" <?php echo $_readonly;?>>
    <?php foreach($this->getSupplierList() as $key=>$eachSuppier) { ?>
    <?php ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $key;?>" <?php if($key==$this->getProduct()->getdData('yourattribute_code') ):?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>> label </option>
     </select>
```

Step3:Create a event on catalog_product_prepare_save save it to you attibute

add below code at config.xml

```
<adminhtml>

        <events>
            <catalog_product_prepare_save>
                <observers>
                    <fishpig_save_product_data>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customtabs/observer</class>
                        <method>saveProductTabData</method>
                    </fishpig_save_product_data>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_prepare_save>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
```

and Observe code is

```
   public function saveProductTabData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {


            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

            try {

                $customFieldValue =  $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
         $product->setData('yourattribute_code',$customFieldValue['supplierlist']))


            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }

    }
```

**Edit:**

**Full code in module Structure:**

Step1:
create `config.xml` at `app/code/local/Stackexchange/Magento34338/etc/`

code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
            <Stackexchange_Magento34338>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </Stackexchange_Magento34338>
    </modules>  
    <global>
        <blocks>
                <magento34338>
                    <class>Stackexchange_Magento34338_Block</class>
                </magento34338> 
                <adminhtml>
                        <rewrite>
                            <catalog_product_edit_tab_inventory>Stackexchange_Magento34338_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Inventory</catalog_product_edit_tab_inventory>
                        </rewrite>  
                </adminhtml>    
        </blocks>
        <models>
                <magento34338>
                    <class>Stackexchange_Magento34338_Model</class>
                </magento34338> 
        </models>   
    </global>
    <adminhtml>

        <events>
            <catalog_product_prepare_save>
                <observers>
                    <fishpig_save_product_data>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>magento34338/observer</class>
                        <method>saveProductTabData</method>
                    </fishpig_save_product_data>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_prepare_save>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>

</config>
```

**Step2:**Rewrite inventory  block tab  an this block class Tab.php at `app/code/local/Stackexchange/Magento34338/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/`
and code is

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento34338_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Inventory extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Inventory
{
     public function getSupplierList(){
         $collection =  Mage::getModel('supplier/supplier');
             $Id_list = $collection->getCollection()->getAllIds(); 
                $data_Array = array(); 
                foreach ($Id_list as $ids){ 
                    $data_Array[$ids] = $collection->load($ids)->getData();
                     } 

     return $data_Array; 

     } 
 public function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
    }
}
```

**Step3**:Observer code `at  Observer.php` at `app/code/local/Stackexchange/Magento34338/Model code` is

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento34338_Model_Observer{

  public function saveProductTabData($observer)
    {
            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
            try {
                $customFieldValue =  $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getPost();

                $product->setData('youattibutecode',$customFieldValue['supplierlist']);

            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }

    }
}
```

**Step4**: at last add below code

```
at 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/tab/inventory.phtml
```

code is

```
 <?php
$this->getSupplierList();
 ?>
             <td class="label"><label for="inventory_manage_stock"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Manage Supplier') ?></label></td>
 <td class="value">

    <select id="supplierlist" name="supplierlist" class="select" <?php echo $_readonly;?>>
    <?php foreach($this->getSupplierList() as $key=>$eachSuppier) { ?>
    <?php ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key;?>" <?php if($key==$this->getProduct()->getData('you_product_attribute') ):?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>> <?php echo $eachSuppier['youefilename'];?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </td>  
</tr>
```

**step5**:`Stackexchange_Magento34338.xml at app/etc/module/`

code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
            <Stackexchange_Magento34338>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
                <active>true</active>
            </Stackexchange_Magento34338>
    </modules>  
</config>
```

**Note**:`create an attribute of text type by using inventory tab's supplierlist field update this attrbiue`

Comment: Hi Amit, step 1 and 2 done, but step 3 is not complete can u give any help

Comment: Step 1 :- public function getSupplierList(){
     $collection = Mage::getModel('supplier/supplier');
     
     $Id_list = $collection->getCollection()->getAllIds();
          
     $data_Array = array();
     foreach ($Id_list as $ids){
      $data_Array[$ids] = $collection->load($ids)->getData();
     }
     
     return $data_Array; 
    }

Comment: in which  table you want to save data.your table or product table?

Comment: i want save as product attribute . or any other option

Comment: wait give you solution

Comment: i was create a class ABC_Supplier_Model_Observer , and copy saveProductTabData function inside this class and changed "yourattribute_code" also but not worked

Comment: just give me 15min i will provide answer

Comment: hey check the answer

Comment: great help, I will try

Comment: Hi Amit, My work is done. but i think miss  some points , below link was helpfully  for me. And Thanks , Thank you very much for your help. -->>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079549/add-attribute-in-product-information-inventory-tab

Comment: please accept my asswer

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: 
Go to : app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\tab\inventory.phtml

Create a dropdown  for  Supplier list

Create a function here which give list of all supplier list

Step 2:Create a event on catalog_product_save_before save it on you table

module/etc/config.xml

```
 <adminhtml>
  <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_save_product_data>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customtabs/observer</class>
                        <method>saveProductTabData</method>
                    </namespace_save_product_data>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
```

module/Model/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Flag to stop observer executing more than once
     *
     * @var static bool
     */
    static protected $_singletonFlag = false;

    /**
     * This method will run when the product is saved from the Magento Admin
     * Use this function to update the product model, process the 
     * data or anything you like
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function saveProductTabData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (!self::$_singletonFlag) {
            self::$_singletonFlag = true;

            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

            try {
                /**
                 * Perform any actions you want here
                 *
                 */
                $customFieldValue =  $this->_getRequest()->getPost('custom_field');

                /**
                 * Uncomment the line below to save the product
                 *
                 */
                //$product->save();
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the product model
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return Mage::registry('product');
    }

    /**
     * Shortcut to getRequest
     *
     */
    protected function _getRequest()
    {
        return Mage::app()->getRequest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MY Answer is extend form   [image]  and  [image] are given solutions

**Step 1:** 
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Inventory.php

to

app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Inventory.php

Create a function here which give list of all supplier list 
Like as

**Step 2:**
goto app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/tab/inventory.phtml create drop down using step1 define function

**Step 3:**
goto Database find table "cataloginventory_stock_item"  and add new data field for your attribute code.
else run below query 
/*********************************************/
ALTER TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`
ADD `your_attribute_code` int unsigned NOT NULL,
COMMENT='Cataloginventory Stock Item';

/*********************************************/

End.

more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079549/add-attribute-in-product-information-inventory-tab